# In SugarCRM 7.5 Professional, how can you add custom relationship field?

Tags: sugarcrm

In SugarCRM 7.5 when you open Contacts and view a record in the Opportunities subpanel you can link Opportunity record and set `contact_role` (Opportunity Role) that is a custom relationship field existing only in `opportunities_contacts` in the database.

Now I need the same functionality working with my two custom modules with many-to-many relationship between them and `access_rights` as the custom relationship field.

1. Two custom modules were created using Module Builder and deployed: c_Accounts, c_Users.
2. The many-to-many relationship between c_Accounts and c_Users was created in Studio.
3. in `custom/metadata/c_accounts_c_usersMetaData` I added

`5 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'access_rights',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'len' => 36,
    ),`

and then Quick Repair & Rebuild. I accepted the SQL query and access_rights field was added to my relationship table in database.

4. Next, I added into both custom modules `custom/Extension/modules/{module}/Ext/Vardefs/account_user_access_rights.php`

and I was able to see the field in Studio subpanels and add the column to the subpanels view.

Now, the problem is the columns are shown properly in the subpanels for both custom modules but there is no data shown from the database. How to get the data from the link table into the subpanels?

After the above is accomplished. The next thing is to be able to edit/save the field in the subpanels.

Answer (score 1):

The tools (such as Module Builder) do not support this out of the box.  For example, the Contact Role field you mention is implemented as part of ContactOpportunityRelationship bean within Contacts module.

If you look at how the opportunity role is defined in Contacts metadata, you'll see you need to make sure to add the right "rname_link" to the field definition.  This will make sure that SugarQuery (which is used to populate Subpanels in 7.5) adds the right Join to populate your subpanel.

Comment: Thanks Matt, it was a bit more than that. I followed exactly file by file the setup of `Opportunities<--->Contacts` and I got it working. The actual query sits in the `modules/Opportunities/Opportunity.php` in the function `get_contacts()`